# Minhas funções só retornam 0

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estava tentando fazer a fórmula de Bhaskara em funções, porém algo deu errado e só retornam `0` não importando os inputs que eu coloco. Aqui está o código:

```js
function bhaskaraP(ab, bb, cb) {
 var Mb = bb * -1
 var b2 = bb * bb
 var delta0 = b2 - 4 * ab * cb
 var delta = Math.sqrt(delta0)
 var rstM = (Mb + delta) / 2 * ab
 return rstM
}

function bhaskaraN(ac, bc, cc) {
 var Mbc = bc * -1
 var b2c = bc * bc
 var delta0c = b2c - 4 * ac * cc
 var deltac = Math.sqrt(delta0c)
 var rstN = (Mbc - deltac) / 2 * ac
 return rstN
}
var form = document.getElementById("form")
var a = document.getElementById("a")
var b = document.getElementById("b")
var c = document.getElementById("c")
var ax = a.value
var bx = b.value
var cx = c.value
var bh1 = bhaskaraP(ax, bx, cx)
var bh2 = bhaskaraN(ax, bx, cx)
form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
 alert(bh1 + " " + bh2)
})
```

```html
<div>
   <form id="form">
      Digite o A:&emsp;<input id="a" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o B:&emsp;<input id="b" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o C:&emsp;<input id="c" type="number">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além do que já disseram nas outras respostas (você só deveria pegar os valores após o *submit* e os valores em string devem ser convertidos para números), dá para simplificar o código, fazendo com que a função já retorne todas as raízes em um array. Isso evita que você - desnecessariamente - calcule o delta duas vezes.

Outro ponto importante é verificar se o delta é negativo, e neste caso a equação não terá raízes reais.

```js
// retorna um array com as raízes reais
function bhaskara(a, b, c) {
    var delta = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);
    if (delta < 0) {
        // não tem raízes reais, retornar array vazio
        return [];
    }

    if (delta == 0) { // só tem uma raiz
        return [ -b / 2 * a ];
    }

    var raizDelta = Math.sqrt(delta);
    // retorna as duas raízes em um array
    return [ (-b + raizDelta) / 2 * a, (-b - raizDelta) / 2 * a ];
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // só pega os valores após o submit
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
    var raizes = bhaskara(a, b, c);
    if (raizes.length > 0) { // tem pelo menos uma raiz
        alert(raizes.join(' '));
    } else { // não tem nenhuma raiz real
        alert("Não tem raízes reais");
    }
})
```

```html
<div>
   <form id="form">
      Digite o A:&emsp;<input id="a" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o B:&emsp;<input id="b" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o C:&emsp;<input id="c" type="number">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

Como a função pode retornar um array com uma ou duas raízes, usei o método [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para imprimir as raízes separadas por espaço (se tiver só uma, imprime somente este valor, e se tiver duas, imprime ambas separadas por um espaço).

Answer (score 4):

Não olhei se a fórmula está errada, mas o problema não é por causa da fórmula. Você está mandando pegar os dados "entrados" e fazer todos os cálculos antes dos dados serem entrados, então os dados valem 0 e aí o cálculo dá 0 mesmo. Você tem que pedir para fazer tudo isto, depois que o `submit` é acionado, então não pode só chamar o `alert()` no evento, tem que ser todo o código que pega os dados e chama o cálculo.

```js
function bhaskaraP(ab, bb, cb) {
    var Mb = bb * -1;
    var b2 = bb * bb;
    var delta0 = b2 - 4 * ab * cb;
    var delta = Math.sqrt(delta0);
    var rstM = (-bb + Math.sqrt(delta0)) / 2 * ab;
  return rstM;
}

function bhaskaraN(ac, bc, cc) {
    var Mbc = bc * -1;
    var b2c = bc * bc;
    var delta0c = b2c - 4 * ac * cc;
    var deltac = Math.sqrt(delta0c);
    var rstN = (Mbc - deltac) / 2 * ac;
    return rstN;
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
  var form = document.getElementById("form");
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var b = document.getElementById("b");
  var c = document.getElementById("c");
  var ax = a.value;
  var bx = b.value;
  var cx = c.value;
  var bh1 = bhaskaraP(ax, bx, cx);
  var bh2 = bhaskaraN(ax, bx, cx);
    alert(bh1 + " " + bh2);
})
```

```html
<div>
   <form id="form">
      Digite o A:&emsp;<input id="a" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o B:&emsp;<input id="b" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o C:&emsp;<input id="c" type="number">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Bhaskara.js).

Answer (score 3):

Coloque as variáveis dentro do escopo do submit, assim os valores serão atribuídos no submit, e o método Math.sqrt não aceita valores negativos, retornando então NaN (Não é um número).

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener('submit', function () {

  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var b = document.getElementById("b");
  var c = document.getElementById("c"); 

  var ax = a.value;
  var bx = b.value;
  var cx = c.value;

  var bh1 = bhaskaraP(ax, bx, cx);
  var bh2 = bhaskaraN(ax, bx, cx);

    alert(bh1 + " " + bh2);
});

function bhaskaraP(ab, bb, cb) {
  var delta = Math.pow(bb, 2) - 4 * ab * bb;
  delta = (delta < 0) ? delta * -1 : delta;
  return - bb + Math.sqrt(delta, 2)/2*ab;
}

function bhaskaraN(ab, bb, cb) {
    var delta = Math.pow(bb, 2) - 4 * ab * bb;
  delta = (delta < 0) ? delta * -1 : delta;
  return - bb - Math.sqrt(delta, 2)/2*ab;
}
```

Comment: bom saber que o math.sqrt não aceita valor negativo,mas o que esse"?" no delta serve?(se isso for obvio ,desculpa eu não sei muito sobre javascript e tals)

Comment: é um "if" em uma linha, ou seja, se o valor de delta for menor que 0 então multiplique por -1 se não ele joga o delta.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: ok ,obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Alguns erros:

1. Você não fez o parse dos valores recebidos do HTML, afinal, todos os valores do HTML são strings
2. O calculo deveria ser executado apenas no submit, depois que o usuário digitou os valores.

```js
function bhaskaraP(ab, bb, cb) {
 var Mb = bb * -1
 var b2 = bb * bb
 var delta0 = b2 - 4 * ab * cb
 var delta = Math.sqrt(delta0)
 var rstM = (Mb + delta) / 2 * ab
 return rstM
}

function bhaskaraN(ac, bc, cc) {
 var Mbc = bc * -1
 var b2c = bc * bc
 var delta0c = b2c - 4 * ac * cc
 var deltac = Math.sqrt(delta0c)
 var rstN = (Mbc - deltac) / 2 * ac
 return rstN
}
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 var form = document.getElementById("form")
 var a = document.getElementById("a")
 var b = document.getElementById("b")
 var c = document.getElementById("c")
 var ax = parseFloat(a.value)
 var bx = parseFloat(b.value)
 var cx = parseFloat(c.value)
 var bh1 = bhaskaraP(ax, bx, cx)
 var bh2 = bhaskaraN(ax, bx, cx)
 alert(bh1 + " " + bh2)
})
```

```html
<div>
   <form id="form">
      Digite o A:&emsp;<input id="a" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o B:&emsp;<input id="b" type="number">
      <br>
      <br>
      Digite o C:&emsp;<input id="c" type="number">
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
</div>
```